# Oracle SQL Developer flag my working views as broken

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can anyone share me some light on why my Oracle SQL Developer flagged my view as broken while it is actually working?

[image]

[image]

[image]

It is not just 1 view, but 10 views have the same problem, they are all created in a different time, with subquery or joining to multiple tables and is always working fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the view was invalidated by a change to a referenced object. Like stored PL/SQL, a recompilation will occur when it is next used, when it will become valid again. For example:

```
SQL> create table demo (id integer);

Table created


SQL> create or replace view v1 as select id from demo;

View created


SQL> select o.status from user_objects o where object_type = 'VIEW' and object_name = 'V1';

STATUS
-------
VALID

SQL> alter table demo modify id varchar2(10);

Table altered


SQL> select o.status from user_objects o where object_type = 'VIEW' and object_name = 'V1';

STATUS
-------
INVALID

SQL> select * from v1;

ID
----------
SQL> select o.status from user_objects o where object_type = 'VIEW' and object_name = 'V1';

STATUS
-------
VALID
```